# Eclipse is printing the wrong characters in the text editor

Tags: eclipse

I have a strange problem with Eclipse (Helios). After a few hours of working some of my keyboard keys start printing different characters in the text editor window.

For example:

- `SHIFT+2` normally prints `"` but actually prints `@`
- `#` normally prints `#` but actually prints `/`

It feels like it changes the keyboard locale from UK to US, however I don't change any settings. I am mainly using Eclipse for Android development. No other programs are affected. Any ideas on how to fix, or even what could cause such a problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've hit something similar before: Windows has this evil key-shortcut enabled by default, that changes between installed locales when you press `left ALT + left Shift`, which is needed in many Eclipse-shortcuts. Check your keyboard -settings (or something alike) under control panel, I don't have a Windows-machine to check where you could disable this with right now.

Comment: That must be it - many thanks, was annoying the hell out of me!

Answer (score 9):

To switch off the `switch between input languages` behaviour (as described by @esaj) goto:

Control Panel->Region and Language->Keyboards and Languages->Change keyboards->Advanced Key Settings->Highlight `Between input languages`->Change Key Sequence->Change to `Not Assigned`.

Jeez, what a lot of clicks!

Answer (score 0):

Before you change Keyboard setting (as suggested by @dontumer), hit "left shift+ left alt" until you get your layout back. It doesn't take more than two or three times. Once your layout is back then you can change keyboard settings if you are interested.